# My Wiimote stopped working. How can I return to the Wii U mode from vWii?

Tags: wii-u

My Wiimote stopped working, I don't have another working one and I'm using the vWii mode of the Wii U.

How can I return to the native Wii U mode from the vWii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you can do is turn it off and on again, but that should do it.